# MYSQL case statement not working with simple statement

Tags: mysql

I really baffled on why this simple case statement will not work.

```
SELECT avg_weight,
    CASE avg_weight
        WHEN avg_weight BETWEEN 0 AND 2000 THEN 'data'
    ELSE 'No Data'
END AS wt_type 
FROM tbl_prices;
```

results are like this:

```
avg_weight     wt_type
1050           No data
833            No data
990            No data
```

The column is `avg_weight, smallinit(4)`

If I change the value of `1050` to `0`, then I get data in the `wt_type` column

I have also tried

```
WHEN avg_weight > 0 AND avg_weight < 2000 THEN 'data'
```

but I get the same results.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Using CASE, WHEN, THEN, END in a select query with MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5656440/using-case-when-then-end-in-a-select-query-with-mysql)

Comment: thanks I changed it and got the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your `CASE` statement to:

```
CASE 
    WHEN avg_weight BETWEEN 0 AND 2000 THEN 'data'
ELSE 'No Data'
```

Case statements take two forms:

Form 1:

```
CASE case_value
    WHEN when_value THEN statement_list
    [WHEN when_value THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Form 2:

```
CASE
    WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list
    [WHEN search_condition THEN statement_list] ...
    [ELSE statement_list]
END CASE
```

Because in your original case statement you specified a CASE value as in the first form, so you were comparing (for you first record) the value `1050` to the `when_value` of `true` and `1050 <> true` so it failed.

Instead you want Form 2 wherein you specify a `search_condition` only. [Please refer to the manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/case.html) for more info.

[Here is a sqlfiddle showing this in action](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/26276c/2)